# How to create a dictionary with a fixed number of valid user entries in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

I want to write a Python program that creates a dictionary with a fixed number of entries entered by the user. For each entry, if the user enters invalid input, I want the program to prompt the user to retry until he enters a valid input. Unfortunately this program does not work:

```py
phoneBook = {}
numberOfEntries = int(input("Enter number of entries to phone book: "))

for i in range(numberOfEntries):
    try:
        name, phoneNumber = input(
            "Enter details - name, two spaces, phone number: ").split("  ")
        phoneBook[name] = phoneNumber
    except:
        print("Incorrect, two spaces between name and phone number.")
        i -= 1

print(phoneBook)
```

Comment: Changes to the iteration variable (`i`) are not carried to the next iteration, the variable is reassigned to the next values taken from the `range`.

Comment: Explain what is the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is reassigned at each iteration of the `for` loop, which [overwrites all previous assignments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), including those made in the body like your assignment `i -= 1`. So use a `while` loop instead.

Also a few suggestions:

- You should validate all your inputs, including the number of entries to the phone book.
- You should only catch the most specific exceptions (`ValueError` here), so you rarely need to catch all exceptions (`BaseException`)—when you do not know specifically which exceptions to catch, catch `Exception`, not `BaseException`. Your expression-less except clause `except:` [catches all exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), so it is equivalent to the except clause `except BaseException:`. `BaseException` catches (besides `Exception`) `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt`, and `GeneratorExit`, which you usually do not want to catch (cf. the [Python exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)).
- You should follow the Python naming convention `lower_case_with_underscores` for function and variable names, not `mixedCase` (cf. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)).

The new program:

```py
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("Enter number of entries to phone book: ")
        i = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input, enter a number.")
    else:
        break

phone_book = {}

while i:
    try:
        user_input = input("Enter contact (name, 2 spaces, phone number): ")
        name, phone_number = user_input.split("  ")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input, enter 2 spaces between name and phone number.")
    else:
        phone_book[name] = phone_number
        i -= 1

print(phone_book)
```

An algorithmic pattern appears therefore you can create a function that encapsulates it so that you *do not repeat yourself* (cf. the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```py
def prompt(condition, message, warning, validate, process, new):
    output = None
    while condition:
        try:
            user_input = input(message)
            valid_input = validate(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            print(warning)
        else:
            output = process(valid_input)
            condition = new(condition)
    return output


condition = True
message = "Enter number of entries to phone book: "
warning = "Invalid input, enter a number."
validate = lambda x: int(x)
process = lambda x: x
new = lambda x: False
entry_count = prompt(condition, message, warning, validate, process, new)

condition = entry_count
message = "Enter contact (name, 2 spaces, phone number): "
warning = "Invalid input, enter 2 spaces between name and phone number."
validate = lambda x: x.split("  ") if x.index("  ") else None
phone_book = {}
process = lambda x: phone_book.update({x[0]: x[1]})
new = lambda x: x - 1
prompt(condition, message, warning, validate, process, new)

print(phone_book)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could amend your for loop to, instead of using a try catch block, use a `while` conditional to validate against your input, i.e. `while the user input is not valid, prompt the user for a new input`. That would make your for loop be:

```py
    for i in range(numberOfEntries):
        details = input("Enter details - name, two spaces, then number: ").split("  ")
        while len(details) != 2:
            print("Incorrect, two spaces between name and number...")
            details = input("Enter details - name, two spaces, then number: ").split("  ")
        name, phoneNumber = details
        phoneBook[name] = phoneNumber
```